# Creating folders, subfolder, another subfolder and saving custom file name based on cell value vba

Tags: excel, vba, directory, save

I am trying to check to see if folder 1, 2, and 3 in a path are present.

Ex: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\Folder 1\Folder 2\Folder 3\

If they aren't present, it should create each folder and then save the workbook in Folder 3.
All folder names and the file name are dependent on cell values.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
     Sub Macro1()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim individualFolders() As String
Dim tempFolderPath As String
Dim arrayElement As Variant

folderPath = "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents" & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").Value & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Value & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C10").Value

individualFolders = Split(folderPath, "\")

For Each arrayElement In individualFolders

    tempFolderPath = tempFolderPath & arrayElement & "\"

    If Dir(tempFolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then

        MkDir tempFolderPath

     End If

Next arrayElement

strFilename = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value 'New file name
strDefpath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").Value & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Value & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C10").Value
If IsEmpty(strDirname) Then Exit Sub
If IsEmpty(strFilename) Then Exit Sub

MkDir strDefpath & "\" & strDirname
strPathname = strDefpath & "\" & strDirname & "\" & strFilename 'create total string

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPathname & ".xlsm", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Please check that all variables are defined properly. For example `strFilename` seems not to bedefined . Just a cursory look only.

Comment: The first obvious error I see is this: `"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents"` - It should be `"C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Documents"` - but there are probably more errors in your code if you made that mistake.

Comment: Use [MakeSureDirectoryPathExists](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/MakeSureDirectoryPathExists.shtml)! This will also give you control if the Path has been created because you do not check for valid directory names-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing syntax which is normally used in `cmd` i.e. Command Prompt with `vba`.

Note that `%USERNAME%` is an environment variable which is readily available in Command Prompt but not in Excel.

However, it is possible to invoke Command Prompt from VBA like below.

```
folderpath = Chr(34) & "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10").Value & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B10").Value & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C10").Value & Chr(34)
Shell "cmd /k mkdir " & folderpath, vbHide
```

This should be able to create all non-existing folders (starting from cell A10 to C10) in one go!

Comment: This solution does not really tell you if the directory has been created or exists.

Comment: @Storax Agreed. However, if folder exists then the code doesn't affect the existing contents of the folder. In this particular case, OP's intention is to create folders and sub-folders if they don't exist and above solution does it.

Comment: Not quite, as you will not get the information that a directory was not created in case the name was not valid.